# "dasBlog" or "BlogEngine.Net" on "discountasp"

Tags: asp.net, blogs

does anyone have "dasBlog" or "BlogEngine.Net" running on discountAsp.net without problems ?

I have some Problems and searched here, wrote support tickets, googling with bing and trying so many things but nothing makes me 100% happy.

iam getting "Object moved to here" on both blog engines and other things.
On BlogEngine.Net i dont like that the hoster url is visible in the html source.
On "dasBlog" i could not edit the Blogroll.

i only want one of the blog running 100% under my subomain which is redirected to mydomain.com/blog

on my local enviroment everything works

thank you all!
regards

Comment: As it stands, this is not a Programming question; it's probably better suited on another site. I can only guess WebApps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the blog was only a simple application in the iis. Setting the folder to an virtual directory / application solves the problem.